# Leibniz Binary Representation of Squares

Tags: binary, pattern-recognition, square-numbers

Leibniz claims to have found patterns in the square numbers and their binary representations. I cannot see any patterns at all. Here are the first ten squares and their binary representations, can anyone help point me in the correct direction?

```
1 =           1
4 =         100
9 =        1001
16 =      10000
25 =      11001
36 =     100100
49 =     110001
64 =    1000000
81 =    1010001
100 =   1100100
```

Comment: `10101010101010101010
00000000000000000000
01000100010001000100
00101000001010000010`

Looks like patterns to me.  NOt interesting ones though, to modern eyes.

Comment: I'm still a little confused, what pattern are you referring to?

Comment: These are the 1s, 2s, 4s, and 8s bits of the square numbers from 1 to 20.  The patterns there have cycle lengths 2, 1, 4, and 8 respectively.  higher order bits will tend to have longer periods.

Comment: Correct **direction** is [**right** -align](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Typographic_alignment) the numerals ☺